How can I enable the coupon input box on the customer order pay page?
When a customer clicks on the link to go to their payment page, the 'Have a Coupon?' input box does not appear. I haven't made any adjustments to the templates.
Do you have any ideas on how I can make the coupon input box visible on the customer payment page?
The location I am referring to is:
/checkout/order-pay/<order_id>/?pay_for_order=true&key=<order_key>
Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/-T4dnbDTuPTW

You can have a look at this SO answer link. Use visual hooks to add then your shortcode.
